# How do I sum all the numbers in a list of list by column without numpy?

Tags: python, list

So in Python NumPy, I have a list of list from 0 to 99 divided by 5:

```
array_b = np.arange(0,100).reshape(5, 20)
list_a = array_b.tolist()
```

I want to add the numbers in the list by column so that the result will be:

```
[200 205 210 215 220 225 230 235 240 245 250 255 260 265 270 275 280 285 290 295]
```

I know how to do it in the array version, but I want to do the same thing in the list version (without using np.sum(array_b, axis=0)).
Any help?

Comment: How would you do this by hand? Write out the steps in words first, then try to translate those words into code.

Comment: numpy.sum(array, axis = 0) i think would do it https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

Comment: You title mentions numpy, but your question shows list of lists. Can you clarify and add some code for your current attempts to make a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry! I clarified the question. I was thinking about taking out the index[0] of every list and sum it up and then put it in a new list and continue, but it's not working out well.

Comment: I know how to do it in the array version but I want to do the same thing with the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without numpy* this can be done with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) quite elegantly:

```
list(map(sum, zip(*list_a)))
```

**Explanation:**

- `zip(*list_a)` aggregates the lists element-wise
- `map(sum, ...)` tells to apply the `sum` on each of these aggregations
- finally, `list(..)` simply unpacks the iterator returned by `map` into a list.

Easy as (num)py...

Comment: Is there another way using while loops?

Comment: @Sun you can use loops for this! With a `while` loop this is certainly possible, but I'd recommend using a `for` loop. `while`-loops are useful if you want to evaluate a condition repeatedly and loop as long as it is true. In your case you know exactly how long your list is and thus you know already form the start how many times you want to loop. This is a case for a `for`-loop!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.sum(axis=0)` on a `numpy` array

```
import numpy as np
result = np.array(values).sum(axis=0)
# [200 205 210 215 220 225 230 235 240 245 250 255 260 265 270 275 280 285 290 295]
```

---

With the other `axis` possibilities

```
result = np.array(values).sum(axis=1)  # [ 190  590  990 1390 1790]
result = np.array(values).sum()        # 4950
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
a = [[...]]
sum_array = np.sum(a, axis=0)
```